# Spark JavaRDD generic parameters must be serializable?

Tags: java, apache-spark

If I create an JavaRDD using self-defined object(for example: class foo) JavaRDD, must class foo implement the serialize interface so that I can run it on the cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for confirmation, simple answer for your query is ***YES***.

Have a look at this [article](https://gist.github.com/kmader/1d64e64621e63d566f67)

> All objects must be Serializable to be used as part of RDD operations in Spark

But you can beat Serializaiton if you follow above article.

Have a look at this related [SE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28909680/serialization-and-custom-spark-rdd-class) and Spark tuning [article](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html)